# How can I connect mosquitto server between raspberry pi and windows7?

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

Hello I'm trying to use mosquitto server in Raspberry Pi using MQTT to send a json data from r-pi to window.

Before I use mosquitto server, I used "test.mosquitto.org" It worked well.

I mean It sended some json data to windows.

However, when I turned mosquitto server in r-pi on, the windows put some error message which is

```
opts.protocol = opts.protocol.replace, cannot read property 'replace' of null.
```

Would you mind telling me what it is going on and fix it?

this is javascript on windows code (I use python in raspberry pi)

```
    console.log("start");
    var mqtt = require('mqtt');
    var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');
    var client = mqtt.connect('192.168.1.2'); // IP of main-broker

    client.on('connect', function () {
        client.subscribe('sensor_A');
    });

    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        console.log("Topic: " + topic);
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(message);
        var dataLen = parsedData.length
        console.log('dataLen: ' + dataLen);

        for (var i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
            var data = JSON.parse(parsedData[i]);
            console.log('data ' + i + ': ' + data.time + ' ' + data.tem + ' ' + data.hum + ' ' + data.gas);
}
    });
```

I am using two r-pi which is sub-borker and main-broker.

sub-broker just send some sensor data as json and main-broker controls the json data and send again as json to windows.

I think my writing is quite complex to understand.

In short, I don't want to use "test.mosquitto.org" in r-pi so I turn mosquitto server on in r-pi to send data to window, however, there a error in window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove the line connecting to test.mosquitto.org as that will just confuse things.

Secondly you have missed out the `mqtt://` from the URL for the local instance of mosquitto. The error is points out it can not find the protocol from the url.

```
console.log("start");
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.1.2'); // IP of main-broker

client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('sensor_A');
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log("Topic: " + topic);
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(message);
    var dataLen = parsedData.length
    console.log('dataLen: ' + dataLen);

    for (var i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
        var data = JSON.parse(parsedData[i]);
        console.log('data ' + i + ': ' + data.time + ' ' + data.tem + ' ' + data.hum + ' ' + data.gas);
    }
});
```